# CakePHP Routing new directory

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I am setting up my cakephp project on a local test environment from my GIT repo.

it is accessed like so:
localhost/projectName/controller/action

However, i get an error saying the controller "projectName" cannot be found.

So, i need it to use localhost/projectName as my "root" directory, and i am kinda lost as to how. I can obviously define a manual route like:

```
$routes->connect('/projectName/controller/action', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
```

but i don't know how i can make it a "catch all" instead of just routing to one specific controller / action?

I hope my question makes sense.
thanks

Comment: You'd be much better served setting up a separate subdomain for each project you work on, so that the URL structure matches what it will be when you eventually deploy it to the client server.

Comment: But how would i go about achieving this on a localhost environment? I use XAMP and place my projects in the htdocs folder.

Comment: That's an Apache / XAMPP question, not a CakePHP question. It can be done the way you want, but it's got some serious downsides, which an Apache virtual host solution avoids.

Answer (score 0):

Iy you have created a localhost with xamp or wamp (and create a folder in www with the name of your project) you just need to write :

```
$routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {

    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    $builder->connect('/{action}', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => '{action}']);
```

Hope i understand your question and i can help you !

AO